# DataGridView CurrentRow Index was nothing error on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

In my DataGridView there are 3 columns which are Textbox, Textbox and Combobox. I'm trying to add values to that row's combobox. But i can't find the current row because it returns me an error and says it's null. I don't how to handle this.

```
Public Shared Sub ListSubvarsPA(ByVal mdl As IScrModel, ByVal dgvStd As DataGridView, ByVal dgvDiscr As DataGridView)
    dgvStd.Rows.Clear()
    dgvDiscr.Rows.Clear()
    Dim grpName As String = My.Settings.str_elem__subvar_grpname_pa
    If mdl.findElement(grpName, False) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim grpList As IScrSubVarGroup = CType(mdl.findElement(grpName, False), IScrSubVarGroup)
        Dim objList As IScrNamedObjectList = grpList.getSubvarList(True)
        For i As Integer = 0 To objList.count - 1
            Dim obj As IScrSubVar = CType(objList.item(i), IScrSubVar)
            Select Case obj.get_discr_str.Length
                Case Is > 1
                    Dim itemindex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(obj.get_discr_str(), obj.str.src)
                    dgvDiscr.Rows.Add(obj.fullName.Substring(grpName.Length + 1), obj.discr_desc(itemindex).src)
                    Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
                    cbCell = CType(dgvDiscr.Rows(dgvDiscr.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
                    cbCell.Items.Clear()
                    For iIndex = 0 To UBound(obj.get_discr_desc())
                        cbCell.Items.Add(obj.get_discr_desc().GetValue(iIndex))
                    Next
                Case Else
                    dgvStd.Rows.Add(obj.fullName.Substring(grpName.Length + 1), obj.str.src)
            End Select
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

In here it's the problem section for me to add values to existing DataGridViewCombobox values because of i couldn't find the latest row.

```
 Dim itemindex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(obj.get_discr_str(), obj.str.src)
                    dgvDiscr.Rows.Add(obj.fullName.Substring(grpName.Length + 1), obj.discr_desc(itemindex).src)
                    Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
                    cbCell = CType(**dgvDiscr.Rows(dgvDiscr.CurrentRow.Index**).Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
                    cbCell.Items.Clear()
                    For iIndex = 0 To UBound(obj.get_discr_desc())
                        cbCell.Items.Add(obj.get_discr_desc().GetValue(iIndex))
                    Next
```

Problem occurs in here

```
Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
cbCell = CType(dgvDiscr.Rows(dgvDiscr.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
```

Comment: It is easier to populate the dgv by setting `dgvDiscr.DataSource = to objList`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes each DataGridViewComboBoxCell items and lengths are different from each other.

Comment: Are you expecting `dgvDiscr.CurrentRow` to reference the row added by the prior statement: `dgvDiscr.Rows.Add(obj.fullName.Substring(grpName.Length + 1), obj.discr_desc(itemindex).src)?  That particular overload of the Add Method returns the index of the added row.

Comment: @TnTinMn i'm looking for the row index of  dgvDiscr.Rows.Add method.